# AVFoundation preview not appearing

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

Swift3 iOS10 app. I put a `SCNView` in a storyboard frame. I put a `UIView` on top of that (Bring to Front) and sized it so it fills only a portion of the center of the screen.

In my `viewDidLoad` I use AVFoundation to find a camera, build a session, add an input, make a preview and then add that preview to the `UIView`'s layers.

And I get a white rectangle instead of the preview:

[image]

I assume I have missed a step somewhere...

```
// 3D scene and vars
@IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!
var camera: SCNNode!
var sphere: SCNNode!

// camera scene and vars
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!
var cameraSession: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var cameraDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
var cameraInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ... 3D setup here ...

    cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
    do {
        let possibleCameraInput: AnyObject? = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
        if let anInput = possibleCameraInput as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {
            if cameraSession.canAddInput(anInput) {
                cameraSession.addInput(anInput)
            }
        }
    } catch _ {
        //TODO handle this error
    }
    // add the preview layer to our imageview
    if cameraSession.inputs.count > 0 {
        cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)
    }
    cameraSession.startRunning()
```

Comment: I've never tried this from within a SCNView before, but what your doing looks ok. If your having issue's id suggest filling in those TODO catch errors in first of all. make sure your getting into your if statements and actually getting inputs, make sure your view and layer has size (check constraints etc), inspect the view. your not trying this on simulator are  you?

Comment: Well the SCNView and UIView are peers with the "outer view", the one Xcode inserts automatically. Yes, this is running on my phone... adding snap. Also, all the ifs are OK and there's no errors being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

OK well this did turn out to be just some missing steps. You have to manually set masksToBounds, videoGravity and the frame or nothing happens (bug? bad API?)...

```
        let viewLayer = cameraView.layer
        viewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        cameraLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        cameraLayer.frame = cameraView.frame
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)
```

Up and running!